# Wordpress: Joining both users, meta and an outside table issue

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I know that this is trivial, but for some reason I am having trouble with it. I have a table that contains the ID of the user and I am trying to join both the wp_users table and the wp_usermeta table to get the first, last and email address.

I can join the wp_usermeta table with the first table no problem to get the first and last name. What I am having trouble with is joining the wp_users table to get the email address.

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results
(" 
    SELECT id, u_id, u.meta_value as first_name, u2.meta_value as     last_name, x.ID as user_email
        FROM $table_name s 
        INNER JOIN wp_usermeta u ON s.u_id = u.user_id 
        INNER JOIN wp_usermeta u2 ON s.u_id = u2.user_id 
        INNER JOIN wp_users x ON s.u_id = x.ID
        WHERE
        u.meta_key = 'first_name' AND u2.meta_key = 'last_name' AND x.ID = 'user_email' AND
         id like '%".$search."%'    
");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified code:

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results
("
    SELECT id, u_id, u.meta_value as first_name, u2.meta_value as last_name, x.user_email
    FROM $table_name s 
    INNER JOIN wp_users x ON s.u_id = x.ID
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta u ON s.u_id = u.user_id AND u.meta_key = 'first_name'
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta u2 ON s.u_id = u2.user_id AND u2.meta_key = 'last_name'
    WHERE id like '%".$search."%'
");
```

I have changed **usermeta** joins to include both conditions (user ID and the meta key value). But, if the user doesn't have first or last name set, this query will not return that user, so you might consider changing **INNER JOIN** to **LEFT JOIN** for the user-meta columns.

And, the main problem was that you have wrongly used Users table. This table is not like meta table, it has actual columns for user email, user name and other things, so you just need to select what you need from it, so you have only **x.user_email**.

Also, I am not sure about the WHERE search condition, because ID column usually is the numeric, so you are better using comparison, and not **like**. If your $search is a number and you have only one ID matching, replace WHERE with '**id = $search**'.